# PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer not reading Tomcat context XML

Tags: java, spring

I have some properties set in my tomcat context.xml file as follows

```
<Parameter name="foobar" value="something" />
```

I am reading these values into my spring XML using the notation ${foobar}. This works fine when I use the context:property-placeholder tag, but when I define this instead as a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer bean directly, I get the following error:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'foobar' in string value "${foobar}"

Old (working):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/*.properties" />
```

New (not working):

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/security.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Looks ok to me..Please post the detailed exception. Also, try to clean you tomcat and your project just to make sure updates have been taken in properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are dropping back to this older notation either because you are forced to use an older version of spring or you are wanting to use multiple-locations with `context:property-placeholder`.

**Older versions of spring**

When using older versions of spring to get this functionality you should use `ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. It doesn't need the servlet container to work as it will fallback to being like *PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer*. So to adapt your example:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/security.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

By default the properties defined in the locations take precedence, but this is optional.

**Using multiple locations with `context:property-placeholder`**

For newer versions of spring you can use the context xml property-placeholder to load multiple configuration files:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties" order="2" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

If for some you want to use the more explicit bean for another reason you can use the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` which is used to implement the xml annotations. But generally people use the xml wiring.

Comment: ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is deprecated, but I figured out that I need to use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: Out of interest if you are using a version of spring that had PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer why are you moving away from <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/*.properties" />?

Comment: I needed to set a custom PropertiesPersister to use, and I didn't see a way of doing this with the context:property-placeholder notation.

Answer (score 1):

The correct class to use is PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer (as of Spring 3.1).

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/security.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

From the JavaDocs:

> Specialization of PlaceholderConfigurerSupport that resolves ${...} placeholders within bean definition property values and @Value annotations against the current Spring Environment and its set of PropertySources.